# Does Blade age? Can he die of old age?

Tags: marvel, vampire, blade

Does Blade age, or is he immortal from old age/natural causes? Surely he can die from accident/murder, but what of normal aging?

Answer (score 6):

#### According to the Marvel Handbook, [Blade](http://marvel.com/universe/Blade_(Eric_Brooks)#ixzz3EwdG2gix) has greatly reduced aging due to his partial vampiric heritage. Since he has been bitten by Morbius, the Living Vampire, his physical powers have only increased. He has become a [dhampir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhampir), a human with many of the powers of a vampire with none of their weaknesses.

- Blade ages very slowly likely due to the regenerative factors imbued by his vampiric powers. His actual rate of change has not been authoritatively noted by Marvel.
- Since he does continue to age, albeit slowly, it is possible for him to die of old age, but I suspect he will enjoy enhanced physical vitality for most of those years.

> The enzymes in Blade's blood made him immune to normal vampire bites, uniquely attuned to sensing the supernatural and resistant to aging. Since being bitten by Morbius, Blade has gained many of the traditional powers of the vampire without developing their weaknesses. He has superhuman strength, senses and stamina, plus an accelerated healing factor.

Answer (score 3):

> but what of normal aging?

In the 1998 *Blade* movie, it is mentioned that Blade ages like a regular human being.

> Whistler, at 58:44: And he's got their strength. This time tomorrow, all of those wounds of his will be healed. He still ages like a human though. See, vampires age slower than us.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you were to [edit] it to add a direct quote of the statement in question.

Comment: A quote from the *movie* would help too

Comment: Haha, sure. Give me a few minutes to find this :P

Answer (score 1):

According to the comics he is aging very slowly HOWEVER at some point he will not decline but instead become more like a full vampire.  If he should die he will likely go full vampire.  He is a dhampir after all.